# Forming a Tuple Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, tuples

I'm trying to make a "Vending Machine" where I can have an array of snacks with each snack being a tuple with a name, price, and quantity. Is this possible or am I better off just using structs? Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

tuple<string, float, int> snacks[3] = {("food 1",1.2,20),("food 2",1.2,20),("food 3",1.2,30)};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `{{"food 1",1.2,20},{"food 2",1.2,20},{"food 3",1.2,30}};`

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: You are much better off using a struct - give names to those properties, `get<1>(o)` is much less readable that `o.price`

Comment: If it compiles, it is possible. Otherwise, you are looking for opinion so this is not a question

Comment: I am getting the error: 2.1.cpp|8|error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'std::tuple<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, float, int>' requested|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done like so:

```
//declare and initialize tuples
tuple<string, float, int> potato("Potato Chips", 1.25, 20), cookie("Cookies", 0.85, 20), candy("Candy", 0.95, 20);

//set up array
const int s = 3; //size of array.
array<tuple<string, float, int>, s> snacks = {potato, cookie, candy}; //array
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax would be:

```
tuple<string, float, int> snacks[3] = {
    {"food 1", 1.2, 20},
    {"food 2", 1.2, 20},
    {"food 3", 1.2, 30}
};
```

But easier for human to work with struct, so you might have great name:

```
struct Snack
{
    std::string name;
    float price = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
};

Snack snacks[3] = {
    {"food 1", 1.2, 20},
    {"food 2", 1.2, 20},
    {"food 3", 1.2, 30}
};
```

You might still have function to convert your structure to `std::tuple` for stuff as comparison, or to iterate generically over each member:

```
auto as_tuple(const Snack& s) { return std::tie(s.name, s.price, s.quantity); }
auto as_tuple(Snack& s) { return std::tie(s.name, s.price, s.quantity); }

bool operator <(const Snack& lhs, const Snack& rhs) {
    return as_tuple(lhs) < as_tuple(rhs);
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f8b979b8366bc009)

Comment: I get an error using your method. I did, however, solve the issue by setting declaring the tuples first and then creating the array.

Comment: @amirt01: Added demo link.